# Is there a way to set specific error messages on validation rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Let's say that I have a validation rule like `"validate": "condition1 && condition2"` and I want to show the user an error message according to the first condition that is not met.

For example, if `condition1` isn't met, the user would receive a custom message saying that "Condition1 is not met".

Basically, I want to map an error code (or message) to each condition and that should be sent to the user (instead of the classic "Permission denied" message from Firebase).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a way to do this.  What you could do instead is use Cloud Functions HTTP triggers as an API for writing data.  It could check the conditions you want, then return a response that indicates what's wrong with the data the client is trying to write.  I understand this is far from ideal, but it might be the best option you have right now.

You can also [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) with a description of what you're trying to do.