# Are DB reads in firebase realtime database rules involved in billing

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Are the reads from the real-time database rules counted for the billing?

```
"Users":{
          ".read" : "root.child('SomeThing/Users').child(auth.uid).child('AccountType').val()=='SomeThing')&&auth!=null&&auth.token.email_verified==true",
          }
```

Here the rules are reading the DB for Account Type.
Will these reads be involved in billing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database charges for:

- Storage used
- Bandwidth consumed for sending data to clients

It does not charge for read operations themselves, unless results are sent to the client. This means that reads in security are not charged.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. Is there any way to send specific errors to the client for conditions from the security rules

Comment: Nope, that's not possible. You'll want to check for common conditions in the client *before* sending to the database. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49310892/is-there-a-way-to-set-specific-error-messages-on-validation-rules and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252101/how-can-i-know-what-security-firebase-rule-give-me-a-error